# Inserting a page break character in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

In [UltraEdit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UltraEdit), inserting a page break character can be done by using your assigned keyboard shortcut (mine is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>). UltraEdit will render a nice horizontal rule to imply a page break.

How can I do the same thing in Notepad++?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no support for this in Notepad++ as far as I know, mainly because standard text files do not support them.

I haven't used UltraEdit myself, but looking at the documentation it uses page breaks mainly to help with printing. Printing in Notepad++ is a lot more basic, again another reason for no page breaks.

**Update**

I've just checked the Notepad++ wiki and found the following
http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Printing_And_Exporting

> Unsupported print features The
>   following **are not** supported as of
>   version 5.6.8:
>
> - Print all opened files
> - Insert a page break (you can try inserting form feed characters, but
>     most modern printers will not act upon
>     it.

I've just tried adding form feed (ASCII code decimal 12) and get a form feed control character added, not a line so I'm guessing you're out of luck.

Comment: Yup it's Page Break, thanks for clarifying (edited the question now)

Comment: Thanks CResults! I'm hoping Notepad++ will support Page Break visuals, not for printing, but for display. I like the way UEdit adds a rule.  
___________________________________________________________  
But it's not a biggie problem though, I can use 80 underscores as a workaround. :)

Comment: um, FF is not Ascii decimal 12. they are vastly different.
Decimal 12 = Hexadecimal C.
Hexadecimal FF = decimal 255.
i don't know if this was human error or clumsy website "functionality". (i know that many times i have formatting problems with websites like this, and i'm very unfamiliar with stackoverflow's editor.)

Comment: FF for form feed - not a hex number.

Comment: This answer made me wonder on how to put Form Feed Character. To anyone that also confused, you can do it by click Edit>Characters Panel and when the right Panel appears, click on Ascii 12. An 'FF' character will be displayed to the text.

Comment: And if you already know the ASCII character code, you can just hold down alt and type 0 followed by the decimal character number on the numpad. In this case, 012.

Comment: The SourceForge link is broken.

Comment: Correct. Using a form feed, it will print literally "FF" in inverse colors and not cause a page break. Thus it is useless (though a workaround is to paste into LibreOffice Writer or Microsoft Word, and print from there (but then you have set the appropriate font and font size before actual printing)).

Answer (score 7):

This is actually quite easy to do in Notepad++. Go to Edit / Character Panel. This will open "ASCII insertion panel" where you can simply double click desired character, in this case 12 (Form feed).

Comment: OK, true... but on my installation and with my printer, this does NOT result in a page break.

Comment: Yes, it will print literally "FF" in inverse colors and not cause a page break. Thus it is ***useless*** (though a workaround is to paste into LibreOffice Writer or Microsoft Word (but then you have set to appropriate font and font size before actual printing)).

Comment: Note: In the insertion panel, you have to click on the actual character (in the character column).  Otherwise if you click in the "hex" column, it'll insert the two letters representing that code.  ("0A" for LF, instead of the 0x0A aka LF character.  Couldn't figure out why it was inconsistently adding it.

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a regular text file, try this (it works for me).
Go to command prompt. Type edit filename.txt.  Control + P, then Control + L.  This will insert a page break symbol .  However, you won't see it in Notepad but it's there.  To check this, go to command prompt and edit your text file again and you will see where you inserted the symbol.

Comment: Well it works, but yeah, it doesn't render a line break ala UltraEdit

Comment: [`edit` is not available on 64-bit Windows](https://superuser.com/questions/553227/edit-command-in-windows-8/635157#635157) (e.g. Windows 8 and Windows 10 64-bit).

Answer (score 1):

The only 'page break' we could come up for our printer was to highlight the text to be printed, click on menu bar File/Print and then on printer menu click on PageRange/Selection, then Print.